# Message flashing without reloading page?

Tags: python, flask

so I have this very basic code which takes some input text and flash a message once a submit button has been clicked.  My problem is that whatever text was enter disappears after the button is clicked because the post procedure reloads the html template.  Is there a way to avoid that ? Thanks , below is my code :

```
class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('index.html')

    def post(self):
        flask.flash(flask.request.form['expression']) #reprint the text input
        flask.flash(Markup('<br /><h2> Score = '+str(5)+' %</h2>'))
        return self.get()
```

Comment: I suppose, so the idea is to pass the input to self.get() which will then reload the page but now with the old input at the right place ?  I thought there might have been a better way to do this, but I'll try that.

Comment: You should not reload the request after a `POST`, instead you should redirect. Have a look at [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  Also, please don't use the question title to tag your posts.

Answer (score 3):

The only way (i'm aware) to dynamically change the DOM is through AJAX.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/

has  a great example.

Basically, create your own api.

have your index veiw

```
 @app.route('/')
 def index():
      return render_template('index.html')
```

call a view api

```
@app.route('/test')
def post(object):
    getIt= request.args.listvalues()[0]
    More code...
    result=Markup('<br /><h2> Score = '+str(5)+' %</h2>')
    return jsonify(result)
```

in your HTML, something like (this is not real code)

```
<script>
var $whateves= $("#whateves").whateves({
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/test', {
 do something?
  }, function(data) {
    $("#result").text(data.result);
  });
```

to show the new result

```
 <span id=result>No message to flash</span>
```